# Compiling multiple CSS into ONE CSS with Laravel MIX

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

My current webpack.mix.js configuration is:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
]).extract();
```

If I have another CSS, let's say 'plugin-1.css', how can I merge both so that I get an output of one app.css?

I tried ['resources/css/app.css', 'plugin-1.css'] but that's not an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to import all the required css into one main css file, then use that inside the mix chain:

app.css:

```
@import 'resources/css/plugin-1.css';
@import 'resources/css/plugin-2.css';

[the content...]
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually use like this

```
mix.styles([
'resources/css/plugin-1.css',
'resources/css/plugin-2.css'
], 'public/assets/css/app.css');
```

Answer (score 1):

You chain them

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
]).postCss('resources/css/plugin-1.css', 'public/css', [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
]).extract();
```

Comment: this will end up with 2 output files: app.css AND plugin-1.css I need them to be merged into one file. I tried to force the output file name to 'public/css/app.css' for both but if I do that, I'll end up with one file BUT only from the plugin-1.css (overwriting will happen, not append)